# error: conversion from 'const char [10]' to non-scalar type 'std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}' requested

Tags: c++, json, c++11, serialization

I am trying to import a test JSON file and parse it. I keep getting the wrong data type.
How do I load a 'const char' friendly file?

code:

```
#include "include/rapidjson/document.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidjson;

int main(void){

        //std::ofstream outfile ("test.json");
        std::fstream file = ("test.json");

        for (int n=0; n<100; ++n)
        {
                file << n;


                Document document;
                document.Parse(file);

                assert(document.HasMember("hello"));
                assert(document["hello"].IsString());
                printf("hello = %s\n", document["hello"].GetString());

                outfile.flush();
                //outfile.close();

        }
}
```

error:

```
error: conversion from 'const char [10]' to non-scalar type 'std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}' requested
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
std::fstream file("test.json");
```

As for this

```
document.Parse(file);
```

`Document::Parse()` takes `const char*`, and you are trying to pass an `fstream` instead. Perhaps you can use `ParseStream()` instead. Or read all contents from the file and pass it to `Parse()`.

Comment: similar error  ->  jsonTest.cpp:21:22: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}' to 'const Ch* {aka const char*}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @user3766148 Probably `document.Parse()` expects a character buffer, not a `std::fstream`.